Программа не видит заголовочный файл
Всë лежит в одном репозитории, подключаю через #include файл, в ответ получаю нет такого файла или каталога. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему такая ошибка может быть? В убунту в вс код создал заголовочный файл для проверки того как это работает, но его почему-то не видят.
#include "sum.h"

int main()
{

    plus(5,10,15);

    return 0;
}

Пишет нет такого файла или каталога. В файле sum.h как раз определена функция

Напишите какая ОС, как и что именно запускаете

Если в каталоге, где лежат ваши file.c и sum.h (проверить это можно командой ls) написать gcc file.c, то что именно выводит?

@avp file.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `plus'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status. Вот такой вывод

ПЦ. И при чем тут что "не видит sum.h", если на самом деле ошибка совсем в другом: где у вас реализация функции plus?! Задавайте вопросы правильно! Если бы компилятор не видел sum.h, ошибка была бы совсем другая!!

@Harry plus полностью реализована в sum.c связанном с sum.h

в sum.c связанном с sum.h  -- а, вот в чём дело. Пиши так: gcc file.c sum.s. (в твоём варианте компилятор получает только объявление функции, а не определение)

А его кто компилировать  и линковать будет? Дейкстра? :)

Очень мало информации
Ну допустим, возможно ты записал путь в <>, если это так, то измени на ""
Либо, пересмотри путь, я однажды когда изучал вёрстку перепутал имя файла и вместо style.css написал style.ccs
Посмотри на дирекотрии, путь указывается от пути сишного файла до заголовочного
То есть если у тебя что-то типо такого:
inc
|----- file.h
src
|----- file.c

то в file.c будет ../inc/file.h
Если у тебя UNIX система, то проверь регистр путя, то есть ../Inc/file.h выдаст ошибку
Ну опять же, если UNIX, проверь что пути указываются через /, а не \
Больше сказать ничего не могу
Для подробностей скинь ссылку на репозиторий

UPD:
Тут у меня 4 варианта:

Нету sum.c, определяющего функцию
При комиляции ты его не добавил
Неправильное количество параметров
Вероятно, у тебя в заголовке есть строки:

#ifndef SUM_H_
#define SUM_H_

plus(int n1, int n2, int n3);

#endif

Обрати внимание на название макроса SUM_H_
Если у тебя не SUM_H_ или SUM_H, некоторые компиляторы могут ругаться из-за этого
Также, в моём "виртуальном" заголовке я забыл в прототипе написать тип, который он возвращает:
void plus(int n1, int n2, int n3);

С этим нужно быть внимательным

UPD2:
Попробуй добавить при компиляции флаг -I.
